# Does video capture in openCV use ffmpeg?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I am capturing video with openCV and converting it to frames and have the follwing question:

Does it use FFMPEG in a lower level?

The idea behind this question is that I am trying to reduce times in the generation of frames and was wondering if there is a faster method.

Furtherly, I do not need all the frames and I would like to randomly rample frames of the video.

Thank you! If I have not been clear enough please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select **ffmpeg** or **gstreamer** while building the OpenCV.

```
WITH_FFMPEG=1
```

Flag should be used while building the OpenCV. Otherwise it will use  **gstreamer**.

Comment: Any ideas of which one is faster? How do you do it in python? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot change gstreamer to ffmpeg in python, you should build OpenCV with that flag. I personally used ffmpeg for its pipeline which increased my performance a lot.

Comment: I will do just that. Thank you!